# echo into div problems

Tags: php, html, echo

I am trying to echo into a **div** but I am getting following error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: count on $SESSION['count']
```

when $SESSION['error'] is triggered, I am getting following error:

```
 Undefined index: count on $SESSION['error']
```

when $SESSION['count'] is triggered, I am getting the similar error as above.

Here is the code in PHP.

```
<?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){

            } else { 

             foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
                $value['links'];
                $value['title'];
                $value['page_body'];


                $title = $value['title'];
                $link = $value['links'];
                $body = $value['page_body'];

                $search_output .= "<a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br><br>";}
    }
    ?>

    <div id="topResult">
        <?php  echo $_SESSION['error']; unset($_SESSION['error']);?> 
        <?php  echo ($_SESSION['count']); unset($_SESSION['count']);?> 
    </div>

    <div id="searchBox"><?php echo $search_output; ?></div>
```

Can't i just echo out the results like the `$search_output` variable?

Comment: Have you put session_start() ?

Comment: You haven't set value for $_SESSION['count'] and its not existsing.

Comment: where did you initialize your `$_session['error']` and `$_session['count']`?

Comment: Why are you storing search data in a session? That aside... are you sure your session has been started? Perhaps before your foreach you can do an isset($_SESSION['search_output']) to see if a value even exists, if not, no need to loop it.

Comment: yes session has started.. i added values and still same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<?php  if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {echo $_SESSION['error']; unset($_SESSION['error']);} ?> 
<?php  if(isset($_SESSION['count'])) {echo ($_SESSION['count']); unset($_SESSION['count']);} ?>
```